# Foreach echo out name of element in array php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, echo

I have a PHP array, that look like this

```
$melee = array(  
    "ct-knife" => "link",  
    "t-knife" => "link",  
    "zeus" => "link"  
);

foreach ($pistol as $value){
    echo '<option value="'.$value.'">"'.$value.'"</option>';
}
```

and I want my "Foreach" to print out the names of the links, but it prints out the links.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: With "names" do you mean keys ?

Comment: `foreach ($pistol as $key => $value){ echo $key; }`

Comment: the foreach documentation http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php  explains this very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For associative arrays alter your foreach to use the keys. The following will get you what you want.

```
$melee = array(  
    "ct-knife" => "link",  
    "t-knife" => "link",  
    "zeus" => "link"  
);

foreach ($pistol as $key => $value){
    echo '<option value="'.$key.'">"'.$key.'"</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another way :

```
<?php
/**
* Created by PhpStorm.
* User: jokuf
* Date: 7/19/15
* Time: 8:34 PM
*/
$melee = array(
"ct-knife" => "link",
"t-knife" => "link",
"zeus" => "link"
);

function selectWeapon($melee){
$i = 0;
echo '<select>';


while ($i < count($melee)) {
    foreach ($melee AS $key => $value) {
        echo '<option>' . $key . '</option>';
        $i++;
    }
}
echo '</select>';
}

selectWeapon($melee);
```